# Mongodb error on docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've a `dockerfile` and a `docker-compose`

When I try to run `docker-compose` this happens

[image: photo]

Does someone know how to **fix** it?

**Edit 1**

`dockerfile`

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
 && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927 \
 && echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y mongodb-org

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app &&\
  npm install --global npm

ENV HOME=/home/app

COPY package.json $HOME/library/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER root
WORKDIR $HOME/library
RUN npm install --silent --progress=false
COPY . $HOME/library
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*
RUN npm install --build-from-source bcrypt

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose`

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    command: "mongod"
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
  library:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec npm start
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/library
      - /home/app/library/node_modules
    links:
      - db
```

**Edit 2**

Running `docker ps -a` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsUm6.png)

First container `docker log` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crPeM.png)

Second container `docker log` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhbZb.png)

**Edit 3**

```
mongoose.connect(config.database);
```

That's how I am connecting the `database` on `server.js`

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave us [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung I've tried to add my code but I can't do it because I'm new. When I try to put it I'm not able to post and I'm notified that there is too much code! What should I do?

Comment: You can't just type it via edit?

Comment: Problem with the connection of  mongo DB.

Comment: Show you docker files

Comment: @MikeTung I can't because I'm a new user

Comment: @НикитаСереда done. Unfortunately, I can't write down code but I've uploaded images.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I know, but how do I fix it on docker?

Comment: @JuniorVilasBoas ok, can u show `docker ps (-a)` & `docker logs YOUR_CONTAINER_ID`

Comment: @НикитаСереда done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Docker Compose file has the MongoDB Ports as 27018=>27018 but the error from your node application is saying it is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017.

Because of how Docker's networking works (which is all kinds of awesome) you should change the port to be 27017 not 27018 in your Compose file & update the MongoDB connection string in your Node app to `db:27017`.

You shouldn't use 127.0.0.1 within Docker as it expects that whatever you are connecting to is running on within the same container.

Comment: After change on compose file the ports, should I change `mongoose.connect(config.database);` to `mongoose.connect(db:27017);`? That's it?

Comment: Well, I would change the `database` value in your config to be `mongodb://db:27017/MYDB_NAME`

Comment: actually when I'd changed the port to 27017 an error happened. But if I use 27018 and change on my node app to `db:27018` it does work. So, thank you!